# Server Not Showing Images

Tags: php, image, apache

I've got an image, let's say in `http://localhost/myapp/uploads/image.jpg`.

And i've got a script that pulls this image for display on the home page, like so:

```
<img src="<? echo base_url().'uploads/.$filename ; ?>
```

That eventually puts out the following HTML:

```
<img src="http://localhost/myapp/uploads/image.jpg">
```

Now, when I access the folder in windows explorer, I can clearly see the image there.

However, when trying to show it using the link as specified above - it throws a 404.

A few things:

1. My `base_url()` is set correctly.
2. The apache error log doesn't show the action.
3. The Apache Access log, however, shows the the following: `"GET /myapp/uploads/image.jpg  HTTP/1.1 " 404 1175`

I'm confused as to what exactly went wrong in here.

Comment: Are the permissions to the folder containing your image appropriate?  Try to `chmod` it to 755.

Comment: Troubleshooting step 1: if you type the url manually, does it work?

Comment: doesn't work if I type it manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So - The soultion proves to be simpler than i thought.

I opened up my .htaccess file (which cancels out the use of index.php) and changed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

To:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
Options -Indexes
```

Which solves the problem.

Apparently I used a .htaccess that prevents images from  being shown....if somebody could explain exactly what these several lines of code do - I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

your `<img>` tag doesn’t seem right:

```
<img src="<? echo base_url().'uploads/.$filename ; ?>
```

Shouldn’t it be:

```
<img src="<? echo base_url() . 'uploads/' . $filename ; ?>" />
```

And to avoid you going insane with issues like this again, I highly recommend avoiding template code format like this & instead do this:

```
$img_url = base_url() . 'uploads/' . $filename ;
echo "<img src=" . $img_url . " />";
```

I personally think using inline PHP code mixed with HTML is a massive debugging headache that should be avoided at all costs.

**EDIT** Also, what happens when you attempt to load it via the browser directly? or for that matter, when you are in the command line/terminal, what is the response you get when using:

```
curl -I http://localhost/myapp/uploads/image.jpg
```

That should return the full headers of the image and convey a `200` if the image retrieval was successful or a `404` if the image is not loaded.

And on top of that, when you say:

```
Now, when I access the folder in windows explorer, I can clearly see the image there.
```

You mean by just browsing the file system? You need to get the full URL as it would be via the browser. Perhaps your image has some uppercase/lowercase issues? Or maybe even a stray space at the beginning or end of the filename?  But in general, this is a fairly straightforward issue to debug.

Comment: I'll take you up on the tip - yet not sure if that is the soultion....still doesn't work.

Comment: I also thought so, but it just won't work. I tried everything - folddr permissions, no php just html, restarting the server - and i tried curl both in the cmd prompt and windows powershell, and the curl doesnt even work..... im really stuck here. The images just wont show for some odd reason....

Answer (score 2):

Should be `'uploads/'`

```
  <img src="<? echo base_url().'uploads/'.$filename ; ?>
```

instead of

```
 <img src="<? echo base_url().'uploads/.$filename ; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, but no cigar. Something with the server perhaps?

Comment: If you used the image server make sure it takes the server domain path instead of `localhost`

Comment: it's a dev project...not yet uploaded

Comment: Copy the image src url into browser window and check the image availability in the locations

Comment: If there is no image in specified location, then the browser showing as broken image

Comment: It soed show it as a broken image - now, how do i make it show to original picture?

Comment: You manually paste the image into the specified location and it is filename should be as specified in the code. or if not rename the file name appropriately

Comment: If you have the original image, You can manually copy & paste the image into the specified upload location and it is filename should be as specified or if not rename the file name appropriately

Answer (score 1):

You are missing closing quote and bracket at the end,  `" />`

Not `'uploads/.$filename` should be `'uploads/'.$filename`

```
<img src="<? echo base_url().'uploads/'.$filename ; ?>"/>
```